# Meaning of hardware platform in uname command ouput

Tags: architecture, cpu-architecture

```
 man uname
    -m, --machine             print the machine hardware name
    -i, --hardware-platform   print the hardware platform or "unknown"
```

What exactly is meant by hardware platform here and how is it different from the "machine hardware name"? I found some related questions on SE but there seems to be some contradictions among the accepted answers. Where can I find accurate information about this nomenclature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more info in `info uname`:

```
`-i'
`--hardware-platform'
     Print the hardware platform name (sometimes called the hardware
     implementation).  Print `unknown' if the kernel does not make this
     information easily available, as is the case with Linux kernels.

`-m'
`--machine'
     Print the machine hardware name (sometimes called the hardware
     class or hardware type).
```

Basically classification types - you can have different hw implementations (-i) but with/in the same hw class (-m).

Used, for example, to differentiate between kernel modules shared by the same hw class and modules specific to a certain hw implementation.

Comment: thanks! somehow my system (fedora 20) doesn't show these in theo output of `info uname`. I'll try to find the source of `uname` implementation to see where the program gets these information from. That will make it more clear.

Comment: On Linux, `uname -i` is always `unknown`, so it can't be used to differentiate between kernel modules.

Comment: Maybe on stock linux, but on embedded systems customisations might touch that area as well.

Comment: Not with the usual `uname` on Linux... (But yes, there's nothing preventing a specific system having its own `uname`.)

Answer (score 4):

[POSIX `uname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html) defines `-m` but not `-i`. `-m` outputs the machine name as returned by the [`uname(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uname.html) system call, in the `machine` entry of the [`utsname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_utsname.h.html) structure. The possibles values are implementation-dependent; on Linux systems it's the kernel's architecture (`x86_64`, `i686`...), and [can be modified by the process’ personality](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277496/86440).

To get an idea of the variety of machine names used, check out [`config.guess`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD#l158): the first element of each set of values is a machine name, and you'll see `macppc`, `alpha`, `Alpha`, `21064`...

[GNU `coreutils`' `uname`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/uname-invocation.html#uname-invocation) defines `-i` as outputting the hardware platform name, if it can be determined. To understand what that means you need to look at [the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/uname.c#n344). If the system `uname` was built on supports `sysinfo(SI_PLATFORM, ...)` (which the [`autoconf` macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_check_posix_sysinfo.html) claims is POSIX, but I haven't been able to verify that), then the hardware platform returned there is used. This works on SunOS and Solaris for example, but not on Linux. If `sysinfo` isn't usable, the `sys/sysctl.h` include is checked for `HW_MODEL` and `HW_MACHINE_ARCH`, and if they're both defined then the model given by `sysctl()` is used instead. This works on some BSD-type platforms.

In summary both values are implementation-dependent so it's hard to ascribe real meaning to them.

Comment: wow. that's a great answer! thank you! In "on Linux systems it's the kernel's architecture", by kernel's architecture you mean the architecture the OS was compiled for? For example if I run a 32 bit Linux on a 64 bit machine, `uname -m` should give me i686 and not x86_64. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, it's the architecture the kernel was compiled for.