# Why does uname -m report differently in chroot and schroot environment?

Tags: linux, chroot, debootstrap, schroot

I am running `Ubuntu 14.04.2, 64 bit` host system. Using `debootstrap`, I installed a minimal `Ubuntu 14.04.2, 32 bit` system in `trusty32` directory. This is what my `schroot` configuration look like:

```
[trusty_i386]
description=Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty for i386
directory=/home/dipanjan/trusty32
personality=linux32
root-users=dipanjan
type=directory
users=dipanjan
```

I logged in to the 32-bit jail once using `chroot`, next time using `schroot`. Astonishingly, the output of `uname -m` differs. In `chroot` session, `x86_64` (host system architecture) is returned while in `schroot` session, `i686` (guest system architecture) is returned. Can someone explain this discrepancy?

```
$ sudo chroot trusty32/
(trusty_i386)root@dipanjan-OptiPlex-960:/# uname -m
x86_64
(trusty_i386)root@dipanjan-OptiPlex-960:/# exit
exit
$ schroot -c trusty_i386
(trusty_i386)dipanjan@dipanjan-OptiPlex-960:~$ uname -m
i686
(trusty_i386)dipanjan@dipanjan-OptiPlex-960:~$ exit
logout
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chroot` doesn't change processes' [personality](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) by default, so within the `chroot` you still see the host's (kernel) architecture, `x86_64`.

On the other hand you've set up your `trusty_i386` `schroot` with a `linux32` personality, so `schroot` runs that when setting the `chroot` up — and `linux32` (which links to [`setarch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setarch.8.html)) changes the current personality to report a 32-bit kernel architecture, `i686`.