# Is there a portable way to get the processor type from a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, cpu, posix

With GNU coreutils, `uname --processor` or `uname -p` displays the processor type. For example, `x86_64`. However, the `--processor` and `-p` options are not specified by POSIX. Is there a portable way to get the processor type when using the `sh` shell?

Comment: The `-m` option to `uname` is mentioned in the POSIX standard ("hardware type"). Could you say something about what you're using this for that makes it impossible to use `uname -m`? Note that the _output_ is not standardized, so `uname -m` could report `x86_64` on one Unix and `amd64` on another Unix, on the same physical machine.

Comment: Do you want the physical processor type, or the runtime environment’s architecture? ([Why does uname -m report differently in chroot and schroot environment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277486/86440))