# `uname -m` valid values

Tags: architecture, cpu-architecture

On my computer, `uname -m` prints `x86_64` as output. What is the list of possible values that this command could output? I intend to use this command from a dynamic runtime to check the CPU architecture.

Comment: related: [Possible values for `uname -m`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125525/14092446)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not aware of a definitive list of possible values; however [there is a list of values for all Debian architectures](https://wiki.debian.org/ArchitectureSpecificsMemo), which gives good coverage of the possible values on Linux: `aarch64`, `alpha`, `arc`, `arm`, `i?86`, `ia64`, `m68k`, `mips`, `mips64`, `parisc`, `ppc`, `ppc64`, `ppc64le`, `ppcle`, `riscv64`, `s390`, `s390x`, `sh`, `sparc`, `sparc64`, `x86_64` (there are other possible values, but they’re not supported by Debian; I’m ignoring the Hurd here). Another source of information is the `$UNAME_MACHINE` matches in [`config.guess`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD#l193); this isn’t limited to Linux.

Note that `uname -m` reflects the current process’ personality, and the running kernel’s architecture; not necessarily the CPU architecture. See [Meaning of hardware platform in uname command ouput](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209015/86440) for details.